# varnish cache real (body) size vs content-length

Tags: caching, varnish

Sometimes, when an object is not in the cache, varnish will send an object that has a real size smaller than the size declared in the content-length header. For example - only part of the picture.

Is it possible to construct such a rule...?
if (beresp.http.content-lenght <> real_object_body_size) { return(retry); }

I wrote a script that tests the same request against the varnish and the backend. It compares the downloaded size with the content-lenght header. The backend, unlike varnish, sometimes ends up with a timeout but the size is always fine. The problem is rare but annoying because the objects are set to long user cache time.

Comment: Can you please provide VSL output to support your case? Please also keep in mind that Varnish tries to use chunked transfer encoding when sending fetched content that is not yet stored in the cache. Once the full object is in the cache, Varnish will be aware of its size and return the right `Content-Length` header. But as stated: I'd like to see some Varnish Shared Memory supporting this case before we try to further examine the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few days I can say that the problem was in occasional backend problems with varnish's ability to send a chunked transfer if the object is not in the cache.

Thank you **@Thijs Feryn** for pointing this out. I knew about that property but until I read it here, I didn't connect it to my problem at all.

It seems that "[set beresp.do_stream = false;](https://varnish-cache.org/docs/7.2/reference/vcl-var.html?highlight=beresp.do_stream#beresp)" solved the problem.